# Putting a banner in the bottow of a listField screen

Tags: layout, blackberry

I have a screen which has a listFeild and button beyond it .. I want to but a bitmap banner in the bottom of the screen but without being actually in the bottom after the scrolling down .. to be shown up on the bottom without getting affected by the listfield size

Comment: can you provide a bit more info? do you want the banner fixed to the bottom of the screen?

Comment: can you add a picture/drawing?  I'm having a hard time understanding what you want, before and after scrolling.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

well I did it on my own ... sorry for kinda bad explaining

well I did this .. I specified a height for each vertical managers and on is scrollable and the other is not

```
admanager = new VerticalFieldManager(VerticalFieldManager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL |VerticalFieldManager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR | 
                Field.FIELD_HALIGN_MASK ){
            protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.sublayout(maxWidth, maxHeight);
            }
        };

        otherStuff = new VerticalFieldManager(VerticalFieldManager.VERTICAL_SCROLL){
            protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.sublayout(maxWidth, maxHeight);
                setExtent(maxWidth, Display.getHeight() - ad.getHeight());
            }
        };
```